# stub template views for action_mailer rspec tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I need to have some specs for a rails mailer not render the template when the test is run.  For controllers, I usually stub the template with `stub_template` but mailer specs don't seem to have a method that is similar.  Is there a way to either stub the template or set template rendering to `false` when running specs?